# OverTheWire wargame server "added as a known host"?

Tags: bash, ssh

I have been using OvertheWire terminal coding wargame and i have accedentally 
ssh'ed the server and it said in the describtion that i there is no ssh.
this message appeared

> Permanently added 'natas0.natas.labs.overthewire.org' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

what should i do so im not a host and what does it mean that im a host?

Comment: FYI:there is no way for me to know the password for the ssh server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "host" in this context means server, and it's talking about the server you were connecting to, not your machine.

On your machine, there is a file called `known_hosts`. This contains the ssh "fingerprints" of every server that you have connected to.

The first time you connect to a new server, ssh records the fingerprint. This is important, because it means ssh can detect someone spoofing the server in the future (by warning you that you are connecting to a different server from last time). Typically, users see this warning when the server is upgraded or moved to a new datacentre, rather than when something untoward is happening.

Your message is just saying that your ssh client has recorded the server fingerprint to allow you to check that you're connecting to the same server the next time you ssh to it. My guess is the server that you connected to accepted your ssh connection, but used it to print a message saying that ssh was not available.

If you want to remove the fingerprint from your system, you can can open that file and remove the line that describes the wargame server. However, I doubt there is any risk from keeping the fingerprint.

If you want to do this this:

On a mac or a unix/linux system, the file will be in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Open it up, remove the line that describes the wargame server, and then save the file.

On a windows machine using putty, you will need to edit the registry to remove the hosts:

- Open up ‘regedit.exe’ by doing a search.
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys`
- Delete the host key for the wargame server.